# How do I get from Amsterdam airport to Rotterdam cruise terminal

Tags: public-transport, transportation, netherlands, ams, rotterdam

How to get from Amsterdam airport to Rotterdam cruise terminal using public transport

Comment: https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Amsterdam-Airport-AMS/Rotterdam-Cruise-Terminal

Comment: @mts, use a Dutch one, like the 9292 in Relaxed answer. More details and more reliable.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy, there is a train station within the airport and direct trains to Rotterdam central. From there, you take metro D or E towards the south (that's any destination except “Den Haag Centraal”) and get off at Wilhelminaplein. The cruise terminal is close by.

During the day there are several trains an hour (6 or more, 4 of them “Intercity direct” trains, which are faster but require a €2,40 extra fee) and a metro every few minutes. Trains run through the night (less frequently) but the metro stops around 1 or so.

For exact timetables or alternative routes, you can check [9292](http://9292.nl/#).